# 'System.AccessViolationException' when calling method of native dll containing free()-method

Tags: c#, exception, malloc, native, free

I use native C++ code to return a pointer to some memory on the graphics card allocated using CUDA to later call CUDA-methods to process this data. This works fine but the data I store on the graphics card is read from a file into a char-array and then this data is copied to the graphics card. Since the char array is created using malloc(), the method of course calls free after the data has been copied to the graphics card. Since the data is rather big, I really have to clean up the array. But as soon as the method contains the free(pcDataFromDisk); a 'System.AccessViolationException' arises when calling the method fom my C# code.
The native method looks like this:

```
extern "C" DLLEXTERN char* getDeviceCharPointerToPrerasteredImageDataWithSize(char* a_filename, int &a_iSizeByte, bool a_bImediateFree) {
char* ptrReturn = NULL;
char* ptr_host = ReadPrerasteredImageFileIntoDeviceMemoryAsChar(a_filename);
//copy char-array to graphic card memory:
cudasafe(cudaMalloc((void **)&ptrReturn, a_iSizeByte), "Original image allocation ", __FILE__, __LINE__);
(cudaMemcpy(ptrReturn, ptr_host, a_iSizeByte, cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
free(ptr_host); //This line causes the 'System.AccessViolationException' when the method is called from C#.
return  ptrReturn;}
```

The method to read the file to the buffer is like

```
ReadPrerasteredImageFileIntoDeviceMemoryAsChar(){
…
buffer = (char *)malloc((filelen);
fread(buffer, filelen, 1, fileptr); // Read in the entire file
fclose(fileptr); // Close the file
return buffer;}
```

I also tried to put the ‘free()’ into a separate method using a static pointer to the char-array, but calling FreeData() { free(_pcDiskData);} the same 'System.AccessViolationException' is the result. How can I read the data into a char-array in native code and free it afterwards, when C# is intended calling the native methods? Thanks for Your help, Jürgen

Comment: You need to provide a [MCVE]

Comment: Hi Glorin, I thought that using free in native code (dll) called from C# would be a known issue and didn't provide my code therefore. Sorry! Now, please find the basic lines of code causing the exception above.